# how does dimension work in ezdxf

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dxf

I'm making a project in which I need to draw several things into a dxf file. I was using dxfwrite but I needed the HATCH function only available on ezdxf, but I cant figure out how to use the dim functions in ezdxf. any ideas?

I have the definitions but there is no clear example:
https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/blob/master/ezdxf/modern/dimension.py

already tried searching for a docstring in the function

```
import ezdxf

dwg = ezdxf.new('AC1015')  
msp = dwg.modelspace()  
msp.add_aligned_dim?
```

Comment: ezdxf does not support dimensions. Sorry, I can not post this as answer, because some people think facts are not answers.

Comment: @mozman, It appears that you are the author of 'ezdxf', in which case, you probably know what you are talking about.  However, the link in the OPs question goes to sections of code that indicate, at first glance, that dimensions are supported.  Some further explanation in your answer may have prevented its closure.  I've flagged the answer for un-deleting, so we'll see what happens.  If it does get un-deleted, you may want to add more detail.

Comment: These DIMENSION related code is just a preparation for a later implementation - which will (maybe) never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ezdxf does not currently support dimensions.

The DIMENSION related code linked to in the OPs question is just a preparation for a later implementation - which will (maybe) never happen.

Comment: Thanks I ended up making an own "library" to use autocad commands in order to create drawings. Just in case anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.tools.standards import setup_dimstyle

DIM_TEXT_STYLE = ezdxf.options.default_dimension_text_style

# create a new DXF R2010 drawing, official DXF version name: 'AC1024'
doc = ezdxf.new('R2010',setup=True)  


#create a new dimstyle
setup_dimstyle(doc,
               name='EZDXF1',
               fmt='EZ_MM_0.1_H25_MM',
               blk=ezdxf.ARROWS.closed_filled,
               style=DIM_TEXT_STYLE,
               )

dimstyle = doc.dimstyles.get('EZDXF1')
#keep dim line with text        
dimstyle.dxf.dimtmove=0

msp = doc.modelspace()
points=[(0,0),(20,0),(20,10),(0,10),(0,0)]
#draw rectang
msp.add_lwpolyline(points)
msp.add_aligned_dim(p1=(0, 0), p2=(0, 10),distance=1, dimstyle='EZDXF1')
msp.add_aligned_dim(p1=(0, 10), p2=(20, 10),distance=11, dimstyle='EZDXF1')
msp.add_aligned_dim(p1=(0, 0), p2=(20, 10),distance=1, dimstyle='EZDXF1',text="test")
doc.saveas('dim.dxf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked similar question on github. This is the reply I got.

The dxfwrite dimensions are available as addons ezdxf.addons.dimlines, for usage see this [example](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/blob/master/examples/addons/using_dimlines_addons.py).

This addon is not documented. I don't want to encourage the usage of this fake dimensions because real DIMENSION support is coming to ezdxf.

That is from the author.
See reply on github issue [here](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/issues/67#issuecomment-458399518)